# Kafka 0.9: Consume from earliest Kafka offset

Tags: apache-kafka

From my reading of the Kafka Consumer configs my understanding was that if I set these 2 properties, then on launch of my Consumer I will always consume from the earliest offset

```
enable.auto.commit = false
auto.offset.reset = earliest
```

While this works when I start my application for the first time, the next time I restart it does not consume from the beginning

Instead, what I need to do is change my `group.id` to something new and then it will resume from the earliest offset.

Could there possibly be some other committing going on?

**Update**

Looks to me like this is a problem with the Camel Kafka component that I am using.
The `org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer` class has this logic

```
if (endpoint.isAutoCommitEnable() != null && !endpoint.isAutoCommitEnable()) {
    if (processed >= endpoint.getBatchSize()) {
        consumer.commitSync();
        processed = 0;
    }
}
```

by my reading this looks like every time auto commit enable is false it will commit the offset.
This is a feature of the Camel Kafka component, in that it will synch after x number of messages even if auto commit is enabled

Comment: You can check is there are commits for the consumer group via `bin/kakfa-consumer-groups.sh` And just to be sure, you do not do manual commits in you client code, right?

Comment: I do not do any manual commits, is my understanding at least correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding sounds correct.

Kafka 0.9 has both "Old" and "New" consumer configs. This configuration property changed between them.

```
auto.commit.enable = false
enable.auto.commit = false
```

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#consumerconfigs

On startup it should be logging its configuration as well, so verify there.

```
2016-10-06 14:19:41,725 INFO [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:165] - ConsumerConfig values:
    group.id = service
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
    enable.auto.commit = false
    auto.offset.reset = latest
```

Comment: Yes, I did verify. I think the problem lies in the Camel Kafka component I am using

Comment: See my findings above